# Играть: кого-то, чем-то или во что-то?

Tags: лексика

Вчера задумалась об оттенках смысла слова "играть". Взято какого-то героя. Актер на сцене играет ЕГО, но дети уже играют В НЕГО. А еще можно играть *в кукол* и *куклами*. В чем, собственно, разница?
А еще играют *на чем-то*, но тут все ясно.

Comment: кстати да, интересное наблюдение! Говорят еще "короля играет свита" (в смысле делает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре В. Даля: играть с чем? с кем? во что? чем? что? на чем? ... Много оттенков значения. Можно еще играть (на что?) на деньги, на интерес и т.п.  
Что касается игры актерской, думаю, что вопрос должен ставиться не от слова "играть", а от слова "роль", которое часто опускается, но подразумевается. Например, играть (что?) роль (роль кого?) Чацкого. Чаще говорим: играть Чацкого.